# How to view all the content in an awk array?

Tags: awk

In my understanding, awk array is something like python dict.

So I write down the code bellow to explore it:

```
awk '{my_dict[$1] = $2} END { print my_dict}' zen
```

And I got: `awk: can't read value of my_dict; it's an array name.`

As the first column isn`t a number, how could I read the total content of the array or traverse it?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can loop over the array's keys and extract the corresponding values:

```
awk '{my_dict[$1] = $2} END { for (key in my_dict) { print my_dict[key] } }' zen
```

To get output similar to that you'd get with a Python dictionary, you can print the key as well:

```
awk '{my_dict[$1] = $2} END { for (key in my_dict) { print key ": " my_dict[key] } }' zen
```

This works regardless of the key type.

Answer (score 23):

That would loop through the array:

```awk
END { for (i in my_dict) print my_dict[i] }
```

`i` is the index.

Answer (score 13):

Array in `awk` is not first class object like dictionary in `Python`. In `awk`, array name without subscript can only use in [two context](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02):

- A parameter in a function definition or function call.
- Name token after keyword `in`.

In other context, `awk` will raise an error.

You need a `for` loop to iterate and print content of an array:

```
$ echo 1 2 | awk '{my_dict[$1] = $2};END {for(i in my_dict) print my_dict[i]}'
2
```

Answer (score 4):

GNU AWK uses multidimensional associative arrays such as:

```
family[me][father][grandpa][name]="George"
family[me][father][grandpa][age]=70
family[me][father][grandma][name]="Katherine"
family[me][father][name]="Vasiliy"
family[me][name]="Ivan"
```

etc.

Sometimes it's hard to explore awk arrays such as **PROCINFO** (because in addition to scalars it has also subarrays: **argv** & **identifiers**)

So I wrote this awk script for myself. Maybe it will be useful for you. You can remove such substrings: `\033[1;31m` if you don't like/have colored output.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
function arraytree(inputarray,arrname,i,member,arrnum){
 if(!isarray(inputarray)){
  print indent arrname member "[\033[1;31m" i "\033[0m]=\"\033[1;32m" inputarray"\033[0m\""
 }else{
  arrnum=i
  member=i?member "[" i "]":""
  print indent (i? arrname member:arrname)"(\033[1;34m" length(inputarray) " member"(length(inputarray)>1?"s":"")"\033[0m)"
  indent=indent " "
  for(i in inputarray){
   arraytree(inputarray[i],arrname,i,member,arrnum)}
   indent=substr(indent,1,length(indent)-1)
  }
}
BEGIN{
arraytree(ArrayName,"ArrayName")
}
```