# Filter columns in string with awk piped with xargs

Tags: awk, xargs

I have some files:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

A given script processes them, logging to this file:

```
my.log
```

with this format: (`filename` `col2` `col3`):

```
file1.csv 1 a
file2.csv 1 a
file3.csv 1 a
file2.csv 2 b
file1.csv 2 b
file3.csv 2 b
file1.csv 3 c
file2.csv 3 c
file3.csv 3 c
file2.csv 4 d
file3.csv 4 d
```

I'd like to get one `col3` value (only last one) from the `my.log` file for each `*.csv` file.

I run this command:

```
ls *.csv | xargs -I@ bash -c "cat my.log | grep @ | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $3 }'"
```

It works well, except that awk is giving me all the columns.

```
file1.csv 3 c
file2.csv 4 d
file3.csv 4 d
```

How could I get only `col3` column? For example, this:

```
c
d
d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your expression

```
 "cat my.log | grep @ | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $3 }'"
```

...the double-quotes around this string mean that the single-quotes are treated as literals.  They don't protect `$3` from the shell, so it's being expanded as an environment variable.  As `$3` is not actually defined by the shell (unless this is in a script that you've invoked with 3 arguments), it becomes the empty string, and the `awk` expression is simply `{ print  }`, printing the whole line.

You could fix this by escaping the `$`:

```
ls *.csv | xargs -I@ bash -c "cat my.log | grep @|tail -n 1|awk '{print \$3}'"
```

...or by moving the `awk` out of the `xargs` expression:

```
ls *.csv | xargs -I@ bash -c "cat my.log | grep @|tail -n 1"|awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: Definitely, this is the right fix @JigglyNaga Thank you so much!

Comment: This addresses the bug in your specific implementation.  But you could instead extract the fields you need in a single `awk` script (without `ls` or `xargs`), using an [awk array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183280/90751).

Comment: Yes, moving `awk` out of the `xargs` would print the right results... the drawback is that output would be delayed until all files are processed.

Comment: Have you tried that and observed a delay?  It's a pipeline, so the `awk {print $3}` at the end will still process each line of input as it becomes available.  And the array method will have to read the whole of `my.log` before printing its results, but only needs to read it once.

Comment: You are absolutely right @JigglyNaga I was guessing but wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Piping the output of `ls` into `xargs` is a bad idea (in fact, doing anything with the output of `ls` other than simply viewing it in your terminal is a [bad idea](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)).   If you absolutely must do something like this, at least use something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.csv' -print0` and pipe that into `xargs -0r`.

But, in thise case, you don't need to do it at all because the filenames of your .csv files are **already in `my.log`**.

In awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ seen[$1] = $3 }

END {
  for (f in seen) { print seen[f] };
}
```

or as a one-liner:

```
$ awk '{seen[$1] = $3}; END {for (f in seen) { print seen[f] };}' my.log 
c
d
d
```

These will print the last value seen in column 3 for each file listed in column 1.

If you want it to print only the first value seen in column 3, change it to:

```
!seen[$1] { seen[$1] = $3 }
```

---

If you don't want to use `find | xargs` and 
you really need to use the filenames of all the `.csv` files currently in the current directory, one alternative is to do something like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $logfile=shift;      # get the first arg (the logfile name)

my $re=join("|",@ARGV); # turn the remaining args into a regular expression

@ARGV=$logfile;         # set the logfile name as the sole cmd-line argument.

my %seen=();

while(<>) {
   next unless (m/^($re)/o); # ignore any filenames that weren't on the cmd line.
   my(@F) = split;
   $seen{$F[0]} = $F[2];  # perl arrays start from 0, not 1.
};

foreach my $file (sort keys %seen) {
  print $seen{$file}, "\n";
};
```

save it as, e.g. `nandro.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x` and run it as:

```
$ ./nandro.pl my.log *.csv
c
d
d
```

Comment: awesome, @cas! `awk` script looks very elegant :-)

Comment: elegant and it runs many times faster than running `bash -c "cat | grep | tail | awk"` for each .csv file.  Both the awk and perl versions make only **one** pass through `my.log`.  Your `xargs`-based  "loop" makes one pass per .csv file.